# How to know $(window).load(); status from jquery

Tags: jquery, progress

I have created a website loading progress bar using Jquery UI Progress bar. This progress bar shows the status of scripts loading. A sample is

```
$.getScript('_int/ajax.js',function() {
    $("#progressinfo").html("Loading Complete ...");
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 100 });
});
```

This progress bar is in `#indexloader` which is blocking the website being loaded behind, its CSS is:

```
#indexloader {
    z-index:100;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#FFF;
    width:100%;height:100%;
}
```

After the progress bar reaches `100%`, I want to hide and remove `#indexloader` for that I used

```
$("#indexloader").fadeOut("slow",function() { $("#indexloader").remove(); });
```

But the problem is,  although the scripts have loaded, the pages are not fully loaded, I see images and other things still loading.

So before fading and removing the `#indexloader` I want to check whether the `$(window).load()` has completed or not

Is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a property to `window`:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    window.loaded = true;
});
```

Then check `window.loaded` before you hide `#indexloader`.

Answer (score 1):

Is fading out the loader on `window.load` an option? Seems like the easiest way to do what you want:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#indexloader").fadeOut("slow",function() { $("#indexloader").remove(); });
});
```

Alternatively, set a variable on `window.load`, like this:

```
var loaded = false;
$(window).load(function() { loaded = true; });
```

Then change your fadeout code to look for it:

```
function fadeIndex() {
  $("#indexloader").fadeOut("slow",function() { $("#indexloader").remove(); });
}
if (loaded) fadeIndex(); //aleady loaded
else $(window).load(fadeIndex); //fade when we do load
```

Comment: Both of you answer at *exactly* the same time. And I have an almost verbatim answer prepared, and was literally about .5 seconds too slow. Well done guys. Snap! And +1 to both.

Comment: @karim -Hehe nice! I was slowwww today, got beat to the punch about 10 times myself as well

Comment: you are right, 

$(window).load(function() {
  $("#indexloader").fadeOut("slow",function() { $("#indexloader").remove(); });
});

would be easier, but I want to fade after my progress bar reaches 100, in this case, the $("#indexloader") starts to fade before the progress reaches 100

Comment: @Starx - In that case you can use the second method to fade it out when ready, just stick the window code and function with your global stuff and the `if/else` where you want to trigger the fade.